# Can't connect to remote mongodb with mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am attempting to connect to a remote mongodb service and cannot figure out how to get it to work. The remote `mongod` is running on an Ubuntu box. I am a very novice unix user, but I'm reasonably certain the problem is that I am not opening up the firewall probably with `iptables`, I've tried the commands in the mongodb docs and still no success.

mongodb.conf relevant rules

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017
auth = false
```

netstat -A

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:28017                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:27017                 *:*                     LISTEN
```

iptables -L -n

```
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:27017 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:28017 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:27017 state ESTABLISHED
```

iptables commands executed as documented in mongodb docs at - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/#patterns

Here is what I've tried:

browser: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:27017/ no response.

browser: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:28017/ no response.

browser: http://www.hostname.com:27017/ no reponse.

browser: http://www.hostname.com:28017/ no response.

mongo.exe xx.xx.xx.xx:27017 (remotely) `couldn't connect to server xx.xx.xx.xx`

mongo xx.xx.xx.xx:27017 (from localhost) connects properly

mongo www.hostname.com:27017 (from localhost) connects properly

The fact that it connects properly over localhost on the server hosting the mongodb, even when I specify the IP address, makes me think it has to be a firewall issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iptables` rules are read in exactly in the order as they appear.
You now have `DROP` taking precedence over `ACCEPT` of your mongodb ports.

Shuffle the lines in your particular script that sets up iptables and flush and re-read them back in.

If you haven't saved your firewall yet, remove the `DROP` rule and re-add it again, it will shift it down the list and will also solve your issue.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much. With so many unfamiliar technologies, Ubuntu, Mongo, Iptables, Netstat, I didn't even know where to start =p.